# AWS-ECS Deploy got 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: java, reactjs, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ecs

I'm facing with a problem when deploy microservice to ecs-cluster
my cluster

- 6 java (ecs services)
- 2 python services
- 1 react

And I used ALB for routing my request(by path url)

ex: if url is **/javaservice1** -> forward to **service1** target group(with ecs service running)

...

And if url is not match anything -> routed to react app(deployed by nginx)

Everything is good, but when I go to login page, It's good, But if I press F5, it got 404 Notfound.

What is the problem? Ecs-cluster?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile when deploy react app?

Comment: You got 404 error nginx?

Comment: If you got nginx 404, try update nginx config. Something like this:
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

Comment: Oh, sh**, Thanks. very simple, I made things harder than they are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your nginx config. It's the nginx problem, not ecs-cluster.Try this

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
```